# rails 5 tel_to styling issue 'wrong number of arguments given'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to sort out how to style a tel_to link I have. It is generated dynamically when an office location is generated.

my link as it stands is:

```
<%= tel_to @location.tel_number %>
```

when I try to do the following:

```
<%= tel_to @location.tel_number, :class => 'style_number' %>
```

I get an argument error that says:

```
wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)
```

This is my first time using tel_to, i have read the docs but still can't seem to figure this out. any assistance here would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: so there is no way to style this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's much better I think just to use `link_to`, that way you get access to a standard Rails method

```
= link_to @location.tel_number, "tel:#{@location.tel_number}", class: 'some_fancy_class'
```

Comment: interesting, i was told by a mentor to never use link_to for tel numbers, but it works and you get my vote! thanks much for the help! i'll accept when the timer allows!

Comment: What?! What was his reason if you remember that? Can't for the life of me understand why not to use this, it's standard HTML stuff.

Comment: there wasn't a reason given, was just told that tel numbers should only ever be done with tel_to and links and routing with link_to, I think I may have to go start looking into other don't do advice he has given in the past. At the end of the day s long as it works im game.. lol

Comment: Well, some mentors have a tendency to try to sound too smart at times. Good luck with your project!